# Sine motion on canvas: Call function at turning points

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

On a canvas, a circle is moving on an elliptical path: http://jsfiddle.net/NwwsP/

The relevant part of the code:

```
function step() {

    x = Math.sin(counter) * 10 + 100;
    y = Math.cos(counter) * 50 + 100;

    // draw Circle with x / y position

    counter += 0.025;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Now I want to call a function at the vertical turning points of the elliptical motion, so when `y` is at its highest / lowest value. What is the best way to do that?

I tried comparing the previous `y` value with the current `y` value, but that's not working correctly. (Or only in one direction.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you deal with floating point values you need to check the angle with some tolerance as due to rounding errors you will likely never get an exact value to compare with.

I would suggest the following approach:

- Use a step value (as you do)
- Define the top and bottom angles
- Define tolerance = step / 2

Example:

```
var step = 0.025,            // angle step
    bottom = 0.5 * Math.PI,  // bottom angle (=90 deg)
    top = 1.5 * Math.PI,     // top angle (=270 deg)
    tol = step * 0.5;        // tolerance, 50% of step
```

Now you can compare that angle and tolerance doing:

```
if (counter > bottom - tol && counter < bottom + tol) {...bottom...}
else if (counter > top - tol && counter < top + tol) {...top...};
```

Also make sure that counter never exceed one single round by limiting it to 360°:

```
counter = counter % (2 * Math.PI);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/NwwsP/2/)**

A couple of other things:

- You have switched cos/sin. Cos is for x, sin for y or it will go in reverse direction.
- var x = y = 0 does not do what you think it does, y won't be declared here.

Comment: sin vs cos direction depends on which way your axes point - your statement is correct for normal cartesian axes, but if your angle represents a heading from "north" (or "up") then it makes sense to swap sin and cos.

Comment: @Alnitak true, for canvas it points to the right (0deg) so to be able to stay in "sync" with other operations (local transforms, ie. rotate) it would be beneficial to keep it as suggested in the answer. That may not be needed by OP, but I made the suggestion for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    x = y = 0;
    counter = 0;

function step() {
    if (counter < Math.PI*2 && counter+0.025 > Math.PI*2) {
        var maxY = Math.max(Math.cos(counter)*50+100, Math.cos(counter+0.025)*50+100);
        console.log("Max Y: " + maxY);
    }
    if (counter < Math.PI && counter+0.025 > Math.PI) {
        var minY = Math.min(Math.cos(counter)*50+100, Math.cos(counter+0.025)*50+100);
        console.log("Min Y: " + minY);
    }

    x = Math.sin(counter) * 10 + 100;
    y = Math.cos(counter) * 50 + 100;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.save();    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 4, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.restore();

    counter += 0.025;
    if (counter > Math.PI*2) {
        counter %= Math.PI*2;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Here is [my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NwwsP/1/). I think this is what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just did not had time for explanation. Now there is a checked answer as I see.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do without getting too much into math, is always calculate the value of the previous `y` and then when the direction changes, change the value of a flag to help you determine each case, basically something like this:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
w = canvas.width,
h = canvas.height,
x = y = prev_y = 0;
counter = 0;
flag = 1;

function step() {

    x = Math.sin(counter) * 10 + 100;
    y = Math.cos(counter) * 50 + 100;

    if(prev_y > y && flag == 1){
         //Function for lowest position goes here
        flag = 0;
    }
    if(prev_y < y && flag == 0){
        //Function for highest position goes here
        flag = 1;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.save();    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 4, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();    
    ctx.restore();

    counter += 0.025;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

    prev_y = y;   

}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/3daJR/)**

Answer (score 0):

Calculus!

You can find the local extrema (highest and lowest values) of `y` by taking its derivative and finding where that derivative is equal to `0`.

If you don't know much about calculus, a derivative used to calculate the slope of a line at any given point, and the derivative of `y` is expressed (sometimes) as `y'`, pronounced "y-prime."

The reason knowing the slope is helpful is because when the derivative at a given point is `0`, the *instantaneous slope* of the function is `0`, which means the *original function* is neither increasing nor decreasing, so we must be either at a local maximum or a local minimum. (You can find out whether you're at a min or a max with more calculus magic.)

If that doesn't make sense, imagine you're climbing up a mountain. When you're walking up, the slope is positive. Once you get to the top, the slope is `0` since you're not going up or down a slope. Same thing goes for walking between two mountains - once you get to the valley where everything is flat (`0` slope), you're at the bottom.

So... if you want to learn *how* to take a derivative, check out [this link](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/derivative/derivative.html). Otherwise, the quick answer is that the derivative of `Math.cos(counter) * 50 + 100` is `-50 * Math.sin(counter)`. All you need to do from here is find where this derivative is `0`, which happens every `n * 180` degrees, or `n * Math.PI` radians, whichever you're using.

**The quick answer**

You need to call your function whenever `counter % 180 === 0`.

The problem with this, however, is that the interval at which your `counter` variable is incremented will never equal `Math.PI`, so you'll never get a slope of exactly `0`. I'd recommend switching your interval to something close to what you have, but will divide evenly into `3.14159..`, like `0.008 * Math.PI` (which is roughly .02513, but you can fine-tune this as you want):

```
counter += 0.008 * Math.PI;
```

Comment: alternatively, and probably simpler, don't look for the exact spot where the derivative `sin(counter) == 0` because with floating point math you'll almost never hit that precise value.  Instead just look for the point at which the _sign_ of `sin(counter)` changes.  Fortunately you're already calculating `sin(counter)` for the other axis, so this costs nothing.

Comment: Even more alternatively, you can do floating-point roundoff, but I agree, that always has the possibility of not quite catching all 0's.

Comment: Rounding also runs the risk of invoking the "hit zero" function more than once if the degree of rounding is too large.  The sign detection method should be foolproof - think of "edge detection" vs "level detection".